# Img Source string not properly concatenating object variable

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have an img tag that shows current object image.

```
<img id="uploadedimage" src = "{{ asset('imagenes/legajo/' . $legajo->foto ) }}" width="200px" height="200px" />
```

But when I run the page in browser it just shows the following:

```
<img id="uploadedimage" src = ".../project/public/imagenes/legajo" width="200px" height="200px" />
```

And it does not seem to concatenate the object variable that has the file name.

Am I calling Asset in the html tag the correct way?

Comment: Do you use `twig` or `blade`?

Comment: Currently using blade with Laravel.

Comment: I'm assuming this is laravel? It doesn't look like `$legajo->foto` is actually there, can you try it without using the asset? `{{"/imagenes/legajo/" . $legajo->foto}}` and see what happens?

Comment: tried <img id="uploadedimage" src = {{"/imagenes/legajo/" . $legajo->foto}} width="200px" height="200px" />
And is not showing the file name either  :/

Comment: If you just output the variable somewhere on the screen does it display the what is in `$legajo->foto`?

Comment: Found the error, object didint have any file name associated as you said Das. Thank you!

Comment: How do I put your comment as the correct answer? D:

Comment: @LeandroGamarra You don't. The user who left the comment would have to submit the contents of their comment as an answer in order for it to be accepted. You could ping them to give them the opportunity to leave an answer, or you could submit the answer yourself and accept it (preferably do the former and resort to the latter if the user is non-responsive for a couple of days).

Comment: @Das, put the comment as an answer and I will put it as correct.

Thanks Flemming.

Comment: @LeandroGamarra Answer left! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like whatever you are passing over in `foto` is not set. You can verify this either by just outputting the variable in HTML by using `{{ $legajo->foto }}`.

If you are just missing `foto` then where ever you are saving that info needs to be updated, if the entire object is missing (assuming here) you should add it to your return in your controller.

```
return view('my_view')
     ->with('legajo', $legajo);
```